# Angular 8 - HttpClient GET a complex JSON object

Tags: javascript, json, angular, http, get

I am using Angular 8, and am querying an endpoint to get a permissions object.  When I call it via Postman, I get the following returned JSON:

GET `https://endpoint/@{xxx}/permissions`

Returns:

```
{
    "continents": {
        "order": 2,
        "actions": {
            "show": true
        },
        "children": {}
    },
    "car manufacturers": {
        "order": 3,
        "actions": {
            "show": true
        },
        "children": {}
    },
    "products": {
        "order": 1,
        "actions": {
            "show": true,
            "getItems": {
                "type": "GET",
                "URL": "https://endpoint/@{xxx}/products"
            },
            "updateItem": {
                "type": "PUT",
                "URL": "https://endpoint/@{xxx}/products/{id}"
            },
            "addItem": {
                "type": "POST",
                "URL": "https://endpoint/@{xxx}/products"
            }
        },
        "slug": "/products/",
        "children": {}
    }
}
```

In Angular 8, I then have a service, where I want to make an http call to to the endpoint that will return the above JSON.

```
  // GET
  GetIssues(): Observable<Permissions> {
    return this.http.get<Permissions>(this.baseurl + '/permissions/')
    .pipe(
      retry(1),
      catchError(this.errorHandl)
    )
  }
```

As you can see the result needs to be put into the `Permissions` object.

**Question**

In TypeScript, what should this `Permissions` object look like?

```
export class Permissions {
    ...
}
```

I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to add response json schema , as per typescript [basic types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html)

01- the simple way, If you are using Visual Studio Code you can add [Paste JSON as Code lib](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=quicktype.quicktype)

02- Or You can copy paste all json and remove quotes and change values to be the type, please check the simple schema, you can change objects to be classes and add it's reference in the Permissions class

```
export class Permissions {

continents: {
    order: number;
    actions: {
      show: true;
    };
    children: {};
  };

  'car manufacturers': {
    order: number;
    actions: {
      show: boolean;
    };
    children: {};
  };
  products: {
    order: number,
    actions: {
        show: boolean,
        getItems: {
            type: string,
            URL: string
        },
        updateItem: {
            type: string,
            URL: string
        },
        addItem: {
            type: string,
            URL: string
        }
    },
    slug: string ,
    children: {}
};
}
```

to access `car manufacturers` value you have to access this by square brackets because it has space between =>  `permission['car manufacturers']`

for the children object if you don't know it's schema yet, you can define that I have any key and any value by the below code

```
children: {
      [key: string]: any
    };
```

---

Object oriented schema

```
class Permissions {
  continents:          CarManufacturers;
  "car manufacturers": CarManufacturers;
  products:            Products;

  }

class CarManufacturers {
    order:    number;
    actions:  CarManufacturersActions;
    children: Children;
}

class CarManufacturersActions {
    show: boolean;
}

class Children {
}

class Products {
    order:    number;
    actions:  ProductsActions;
    slug:     string;
    children: Children;
}

class ProductsActions {
    show:       boolean;
    getItems:   AddItem;
    updateItem: AddItem;
    addItem:    AddItem;
}

class AddItem {
    type: string;
    URL:  string;
}
```

Comment: Wow that VSCode extension !